# Updated Win XP to 7: network adapter driver issue

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, network-adapter

I updated Windows XP on my old laptop to Windows 7. After installing I tried to open internet connection but Win 7 says that it cannot find network adapter because of a missing driver. I tried to find network adapter from device manager but could not find one. My network connection was working fine on Win XP. What has happened, how to update my network adapter driver for Windows 7?

Edit after comments:

I found from Fujitsu's site, that my computer is not supported by Windows 7. So be it.

Edit 2: Network adapters

```
[ Network adapters / WAN Miniport (IKEv2) ]

    Device Properties:
      Driver Description                                WAN Miniport (IKEv2)
      Driver Date                                       21.6.2006
      Driver Version                                    6.1.7600.16385
      Driver Provider                                   Microsoft
      INF File                                          netavpna.inf
      Hardware ID                                       ms_agilevpnminiport

  [ Network adapters / WAN Miniport (IP) ]

    Device Properties:
      Driver Description                                WAN Miniport (IP)
      Driver Date                                       21.6.2006
      Driver Version                                    6.1.7600.16385
      Driver Provider                                   Microsoft
      INF File                                          netrasa.inf
      Hardware ID                                       ms_ndiswanip

  [ Network adapters / WAN Miniport (IPv6) ]

    Device Properties:
      Driver Description                                WAN Miniport (IPv6)
      Driver Date                                       21.6.2006
      Driver Version                                    6.1.7600.16385
      Driver Provider                                   Microsoft
      INF File                                          netrasa.inf
      Hardware ID                                       ms_ndiswanipv6

  [ Network adapters / WAN Miniport (L2TP) ]

    Device Properties:
      Driver Description                                WAN Miniport (L2TP)
      Driver Date                                       21.6.2006
      Driver Version                                    6.1.7600.16385
      Driver Provider                                   Microsoft
      INF File                                          netrasa.inf
      Hardware ID                                       ms_l2tpminiport

  [ Network adapters / WAN Miniport (Network Monitor) ]

    Device Properties:
      Driver Description                                WAN Miniport (Network Monitor)
      Driver Date                                       21.6.2006
      Driver Version                                    6.1.7600.16385
      Driver Provider                                   Microsoft
      INF File                                          netrasa.inf
      Hardware ID                                       ms_ndiswanbh

  [ Network adapters / WAN Miniport (PPPOE) ]

    Device Properties:
      Driver Description                                WAN Miniport (PPPOE)
      Driver Date                                       21.6.2006
      Driver Version                                    6.1.7600.16385
      Driver Provider                                   Microsoft
      INF File                                          netrasa.inf
      Hardware ID                                       ms_pppoeminiport

  [ Network adapters / WAN Miniport (PPTP) ]

    Device Properties:
      Driver Description                                WAN Miniport (PPTP)
      Driver Date                                       21.6.2006
      Driver Version                                    6.1.7600.16385
      Driver Provider                                   Microsoft
      INF File                                          netrasa.inf
      Hardware ID                                       ms_pptpminiport

  [ Network adapters / WAN Miniport (SSTP) ]

    Device Properties:
      Driver Description                                WAN Miniport (SSTP)
      Driver Date                                       21.6.2006
      Driver Version                                    6.1.7600.16385
      Driver Provider                                   Microsoft
      INF File                                          netsstpa.inf
      Hardware ID
```

Comment: Tell us your laptop's (full) name/model number/type OR your PC specs (if you know them). If not, use "Everest" utility to check what kind of network adapter you have.

Comment: Do you, by any chance, have a backup or copy of your hard drive *before* you upgraded to Win7?

Comment: Fujitsu Siemes Amilo D-8820. I have backup for my personal folders, but not for everything in my harddrive.

Comment: I found this: http://www.driversfix.com/Fujitsu_Siemens_Amilo_D_8820_drivers/dev3403.html 
Will that modem driver fix this problem?

Comment: No Jiri, keep away from such sites. Those are "promoted" or "SEOed" links in Google, only searching for such people. Do NOT try them.

Comment: Also, I cannot find any information about the chipset (and there is no wireless in it I guess). Please install Everest and check what kind of lan adapter you've got, post here the name/screenshot about the info and I'll search a driver for you.

Comment: By the way, checking your specs... Win7 will run quite slow. Maybe if you upgraded to 2gb ram. But also, the Radeon9000 will make the display driver quite problematic.

Comment: Thaks so much for your help! I installed Everest. PCI device is: SiS 900 Fast Ethernet Adapter (PHY: ICS 1893(A)). Windows Network under Network does not say anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Fujitsu site your laptop has a SiS 900 10/100MB network controller.

If you go the SiS site, they do not have any drivers for the network card, nor do they for Vista (which you can sometimes use).  The 'newest' drivers they have are for Windows Server 2003 which I am pretty sure will not work with Windows 7.

It would seem unlikely that you will be able to make this work.

You may want to try using a PCMCIA wired or wireless network adapter.

This wired one by DLink has drivers for Windows 7 so it should work.
http://www.dlink.com/products/default.aspx?pid=DGE-660TD&tab=3